# Opening an .exe and passing commands to it via Python subprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

So I have my .exe program that opens but i want to pass strings to it from my python script.
Im opening the exe like this

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("E:\Work\my.exe", shell=True)
#let user fill in some tables
p.communicate("userInfo")
```

I want to pass a string to this program while having it just run in the background and not take over any ideas?

Comment: Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...]) [Pyhton Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html) or with shell=true something like Popen('E:\Work\my.exe" + param1, shell=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Python documentation for Using the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

> You don’t need shell=True to run a batch file, nor to run a
>   console-based executable.

From the [Python documentation for `Popen` Objects](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) :

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.

Code example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(r"E:\Work\my.exe", stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("userInfo")
```