# subprocess , opening exe file and using command. python

Tags: python, subprocess

Right now i am using this code to run exe :

```
subprocess.Popen(['file location,file'],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)\.communicate()[0]
```

and all goes fine.
But in console i am using additional option to print additional data like

```
in console: 'exe  location' 'file location' option
```

How to add this option to python script like i am using it right now in console?

I also tried this but not work [Opening an .exe and passing commands to it via Python subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860547/opening-an-exe-and-passing-commands-to-it-via-python-subprocess)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add arguments to the list passed as first argument to `Popen` like so

```
subprocess.Popen(['file location,file', 'option'])
```

Comment: hello, this works fine, but i have additional question, i am putting it to the tkinter GUI, should i run subprocess in tkinter different than in normal script to run exe? Thanks

Comment: Nope, just invoke subprocesses as per usual. Note, that it's easy to create a situation where you block the main thread of tkinter when invoking subprocesses causing the UI to be non-responsive, so just bear that in mind.